# AWS Lambda .NET core 3.1 by native runtime vs .NET 5.0 as container-hosted?

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda

As currently AWS Lambda does not support .NET 5 native runtime, it allows to use "containerized" lambda runtime with **.net 5** on board. Trying to understand **what are pros and cons** here to use it instead of **.net core 3.1** as native runtime (excluding new features of newer .net 5 vs .net core 3.1)

Answer (score 0):

As i can see in [this article](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2021/03/c-and-aws-lambdas-part-6-net-5-inside-a-container-inside-a-lambda/) at least :

- Deployment looks almost the same (by difficulty/speed)
- You will need to use Amazon ECR (Elastic Container Registry) additionally to store image